# namespaces and object properties

Tags: javascript, coding-style, namespaces

I have started learning Javascript as part of developing very simple Firefox addons.
The Firefox addon tutorial advises to encapsulate all the functions and data inside a namespace like this.

```
if ("undefined" == typeof(XULSchoolChrome)) {
    var XULSchoolChrome = {};
};

XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay = {
    first_name : new String,
    onmenuclick : function(aEvent) {
        // do something here
    }
};
```

I have a couple of questions related to this:

I understand that `XULSchoolChrome` is an object with a property named `BrowserOverlay`. But then what are `first_name` and `onmenuclick`? Are they *sub-properties* of `BrowserOverlay` object?

If I need to access `first_name` inside `onmenucick` function, it has to be fully qualified `XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay.first_name`. This can quickly get unwieldy for non-trivial code. Is there a more graceful way of simulating namespaces in Javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then what are first_name and onmenuclick?

Yes, they are properties of the object which is references by the `BrowserOverlay` property of the `XULSchoolChrome` object.

> Is there a more graceful way of simulating namespaces in Javascript?

No, you always need to reference properties via the object. However, you can abbreviate sub-namespaces to variables:

```
var bo = XULSchoolChrome.BrowserOverlay;
// then use
bo.first_name…
bo.…
```

Or you might be able to use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) from "methods" of the namespace object. Notice that this won't work directly for event handler functions, which are usually called in different contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Abbreviating namespaces will certainly make the code cleaner.